# AngularJS code for 'controller' does not kick in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am new to AngularJS and do have the task of enhancing existing code.

Simplified, the following is in the html-file:

```
<div class="popup-list" ng-controller="NumberCtrl">
  First number: <input type="number" ng-init="$scope.firstNum">
</div>
```

And this I want to have referred in a JavaScript-file:

```
angular.module('app').controller('NumberCtrl', function ($scope)
{
  $scope.firstNum = 100
});
```

However the modal window popups up providing the input field, but no value = 100 is pre-defined.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: you should use `ng-model` instead of `ng-init` which provides you two way binding feature..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to tag scope in view .

whatever you use on view it'll get from `$scope`.

use `ng-model` in input control in order to bind data.

Like this

```
First number: <input type="number" ng-model="firstNum">
```

You are may be getting module without setting it.

Try like this

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller
```

To get a module

```
angular.module('app')
```

To set a module

```
angular.module('app',[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you have to initialize the module like: `angular.module('app', []);`. Before using it (note the empty array [] that tells angular that you have 0 dependencies and you are initializing a new module).